# How to handle derived classes at UI without switch statements when using MVC/MCP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, switch-statement, derived-class

I'm using a MVC/MCP pattern for my C# (WinForms) application.

In the business logic I have derived classes like

```
abstract public class Item
{
    abstract double CalculatePrice();
    ...
}

public class Nail : Item
{
    ...
}

public class Car : Item
{
    ...
}
```

For the business logic the derived type of an item doesn't matter.
I always can call methods like CalculatePrice() no matter what type the item really is.

**But How do I handle such items at the UI (WinForms) when presenting these items to the user?**
(and of course a *Car* is presented differently than a *Nail*)

- I do not want to have a big switch statement in the UI / controller to handle all types of items.
- I do not want to implement a

  abstract double ShowMeAtUI()

  method in the item class, because this is business logic and it should not care about UI   stuff.

So what is the cleanest preferred way to design this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What UI technology are you using? WPF, Winforms, ASP.NET?

Comment: The project uses C# WinForms

Comment: Could you have a property "ViewName" and pass that into your rendering engine? Something like `RenderView(myItem.ViewName, myItem)`

Comment: But how would the RenderView( string name, Item item) implementation look like? Probably is starts with the big switch( name) statement that I want to avoid...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for the views, correct?

One way I've solved this using MVP is by creating `UserControl` sub-views. I will use a Presenter even for the sub-view. If you can modularize your main view into UserControl components, or if it makes sense to, then that may be an option.

You could implement a dictionary to know which sub-view to add to the parent control's container.

Or, as I recall, I did use a dictionary whose value was a delegate to display a specific sub-view given the parent control.

Answer (score -3):

I don't understand why you need the abstract method ComputePrice.  The price of an item is presumably in the data.  If that's the case, then all you need is a property Price in the base class Item to get the price of any Item instance.

It would work the same for other common fields such as name, description, sales volume, etc.  Then, similar to the Price property, you would add an property (Name, Description, SalesVolume) to the Item base class.

Maybe the price of an item is not explicitly in the data and must be computed.  If that's the case, I still don't understand why this computation couldn't be in the base class.  Say for example the list price must be discounted depending on the customer.  In that case, the Item class applies the discounting rules and the customer that is making the purchase.

Maybe you could explain why ComputePrice must be an abstraction and/or give other examples of abstractions that would require a specific implemntation in each derived class (Nail, Car).

Comment: That's not really the question that was asked. There could be 100 & 1 reasons why a base class is needed

Comment: This is just a very small example to simplify things.

My main question is still open. How should the UI learn how to present things without a big switch-statement for all available types.